# Drop down menu not displaying vertically under main menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Right then... I created a menu which worked perfectly fine but afterwards found out I needed to add drop-down which I done but for some reason it is showing horizontally and aligning itself to the left instead of being vertical and aligning itself underneath the link you hover over. What's annoying is that I did create one that worked perfectly fine on another site, I have tried to match up to coding from the last one to this one but as they are styled differently it is not going well.

The html for the menu is:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu_container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="overview.html">Overview</a></li>
          <li><a href="strategy.html">Strategy</a></li>
          <li><a href="marketing.html">Marketing</a></li>
          <li><a href="team_and_management.html">Team and Management</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="edgbaston.html">Edgbaston</a></li>
              <li><a href="hockley.html">Hockley</a></li>
              <li><a href="selly_oak.html">Selly Oak</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

The CSS is:

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 800px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active {
    border-color: #f9cf19;
}

nav li ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}

nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

nav li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #000000;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Edit: Here is a link to the site: http://vicarage-support.com/our_hostels.html

The link is only on that page, once I have it working and the page finished I will add it to the others.

And one to a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7y6U/

Comment: Ca you put your code in fiddle ?

Comment: Yeah sure, shall I just do the menu?

Comment: or would this be better > http://vicarage-support.com/our_hostels.html

Edit: Just have both > http://jsfiddle.net/e7y6U/

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Hover
add this :

```
nav li:hover>ul>li {
    display: block;

}
```

By this it will come in vertical.
You just have to align the position of it.

Comment: Thank you, that has aligned it vertically but what I don't understand is why it is not auto aligning which is what normally happens when I create a drop-down-menu. Any idea?
In true art attack style, here's one I made earlier > http://www.maintenancebirmingham.co.uk/
This one auto aligns under the link you hover over.

Comment: No worries I fixed it, I put up an answer on how I aligned it so you and others can see.

Comment: All sorted thank you, I would +1 if I had 1 more rep.

Comment: I do have one more question, does putting the > in make a difference? As you can see in my code I put nav li:hover ul - does adding in the > mean something different or is it optional? Maybe a cross browser fix for some issue?

Comment: ">" is called child combinator selector, you can find more info here: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Thank you kindly, that is a very big help and I think it will help me a lot, I am still learning CSS, being doing it for about 3 months so any help like that is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SeeTheC Came up with the solution to get it to vertically align but to get it align underneath the link you hover over you have to add this to the ul li:

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this :

```
ul > li
{
    position:relative
}
```

Just realised it doesn't work on IE

Comment: Thank you, I just realised that while going over a previous menu I made, I also added float: left.